# WordPress SEO plugin only visible to specific user

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Yoast SEO plugin in WordPress and wanted to know if there was a way to make it only visible to one specific user in the db or in the functions.php file? Not a role, an actual user.

Comment: From the top of my head, you could replace the function that checks for the capabilties with a function that checks the ID of the current user, like: `get_current_user_id`, the it just and if and an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an universal solution to simply add "plugin-name" and disable it, but failed.

But, to show WPSEO only to a specific user (`ID` equals `2`), the following works:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'seo_so_25654837' );

function seo_so_25654837() 
{
    if ( '2' ==  get_current_user_id() )
        return;

    remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpseo_admin_init', 15 );
}
```

Don't add the code to `functions.php`, use it as a [normal plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers).

The following is also needed to remove the SEO menu from the admin bar:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'bar_so_25654837' );

function bar_so_25654837() 
{
    if ( '2' ==  get_current_user_id() )
        return;

    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {
        if( !$node->parent )
        {
            if( 'wpseo-menu' === $node->id )
                $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( $node->id );
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I created a plugin with your php code and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to [`pre_current_active_plugins`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/809baf442b0bd4aaedbbc06de8d6d14408a73d7b/wp-admin/plugins.php#L435) to remove elements from the table before it is displayed. Using [`get_current_user_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) within the function will let you selectively hide a plugin.

```
function hide_plugins_by_user( $all_plugins=false ) {
    global $wp_list_table;

    // if the current user ID is not 1, hide it.
    if ( 1 != get_current_user_id() ){
        // the active plugins from the table
        $plugins = $wp_list_table->items;
        // loop through them
        foreach ( $plugins as $key => $val ) {
            // use the dir + filename of the plugin to hide
            if ( $key == 'plugindir/plugin.php' ) {
                unset( $wp_list_table->items[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_current_active_plugins', 'hide_plugins_by_user' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine (Credits goes to [Hislop](http://www.mootpoint.org/blog/disable-yoast-wordpress-seo-for-certain-roles/)):

```
// Returns true if user has specific role 
function check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    else
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( empty( $user ) )
        return false;
    return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}

// Disable WordPress SEO meta box for all roles other than administrator and seo
function wpse_init(){
    if( !(check_user_role('seo') || check_user_role('administrator')) ){
        // Remove page analysis columns from post lists, also SEO status on post editor
        add_filter('wpseo_use_page_analysis', '__return_false');
        // Remove Yoast meta boxes
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'disable_seo_metabox', 100000);
    }   
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_init');

function disable_seo_metabox(){
    remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'post', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'page', 'normal');
}
```

Just place it in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Yoast for all the users and enable it for just for few or specific, just add the following piece of code to your function.php file.

```
            function remove_wpseo(){

                /* if you want to keep it enabled for user with id 2 */
                if ( '2' ==  get_current_user_id() ) {
                    return;
                }

                global $wpseo_front;
                if(defined($wpseo_front)){
                    remove_action('wp_head',array($wpseo_front,'head'),1);
                }
                else {
                    $wp_thing = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
                    remove_action('wp_head',array($wp_thing,'head'),1);
                }

            }

            add_action('template_redirect','remove_wpseo');
```

Reference: https://makersbyte.com/disable-yoast-seo-plugin-specific-page/